# Functions and Loops in Python

Tags: python

I cannot see what I have done wrong below. I am new to Python.

INSTRUCTIONS

Define a function compute_bill that takes one argument food as input.

In the function, create a variable total with an initial value of zero.

For each item in the food list, add the price of that item to total.

Finally, return the total.

CODE

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food): 
    total = 0 
    for item in food: 
        total += item
    return total(food)
```

Comment: Please try to read about the dictionaries in python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute_bill(food): return sum([prices[item] for item in food])
```

This is probably cleaner